# Fade out preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make my preloader to fade out when finished loading? I tried adding `transition: 1s ease;` but I guess I'm forgetting something.

HTML:

```
<div class="preloader">
        <div class="preloder-wrap">
        <div><p class="typewriter" style="font-size:12px;color:#000;position:absolute;top:5px;left:1%;">function onReady(callback) {</p><p class="typewriter2" style="font-size:12px;color:#000;position:absolute;top:25px;left:1%;">var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 1000);</p><p class="typewriter3" style="font-size:12px;color:#000;position:absolute;top:45px;left:1%;">}</p><p class="typewriter4" style="font-size:12px;color:#000;position:absolute;top:75px;left:1%;">function checkReady() {</p><p class="typewriter5" style="font-size:12px;color:#000;position:absolute;top:95px;left:1%;">if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {</p><p class="typewriter6" style="font-size:12px;color:#000;position:absolute;top:115px;left:1%;">window.clearInterval(intervalID);</p><p class="typewriter7" style="font-size:12px;color:#000;position:absolute;top:135px;left:1%;">}</p></div>
            <div class="preloder-inner"> 
            <br><br>
            <div class="box loading"></div>
                <br><br><div id="fadeinvtx" style="color:#FFF; text-align:center;"><i>//loading%</i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.preloader{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.preloder-wrap{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.preloder-inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your javascript, when it has finished loading you can use use jquery's [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) function:

```
$("preloader").fadeOut();
```

Comment: Thanks, I had this function set `$(".preloader").delay(1600).fadeOut("fast").remove;` and had to take off the `.remove` part. Thanks!